# Unit Testing a Web API controller which Has Been Authorized with JWT

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, authorization, moq

I'm trying to Unit Test below Web API controller.

```
    [IdentityBasicAuthentication]
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetOrderByQR([FromBody]string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

            var user = UserManager().IdentifyToken(identity);

            _orderManager.CheckOrderQRFraud(id);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _orderManager.GetSingleOrderWithUserPaymentAccountBy(user.UserID, id));
        }
        catch (BusinessException ex)
        {
            return CreateRawStringResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

But below test method throws null exception on `IdentifyToken()` as there is no current user, I understand that.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetOrderByQR_Returns_OK_On_Successful_Request()
    {
        string orderID = "4B854B3D-397E-425F-AEAF-00F7B4110021";

        var testResponse = _orderController.GetOrderByQR(orderID);

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, testResponse.StatusCode);
    }
```

While I was searching for an answer, I saw that the solution lies on mocking this authorization attribute. So, although I install this [Moq](https://code.google.com/archive/p/moq/) package, couldn't achive to run as successful test as I'm new on unit testing.

Below is `IdentityToken()` method if you need to check it out also.

```
    public User IdentifyToken(ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        string userEmail = "";
        string userPassword = "";

        if (identity != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
            List<Claim> claimsArray = claims.ToList();
            string[] emailArray = claimsArray[0].ToString().Split(':');
            string emailValue = emailArray[2].ToString();
            userEmail = emailValue.Trim();
            string[] passwordArray = claimsArray[1].ToString().Split(':');
            string passwordValue = passwordArray[2].ToString();
            userPassword = passwordValue.Trim();
        }

        var user = base.GetSingleBy(x => x.Email == userEmail && x.Password == userPassword);

        return user;
    }
```

How should I write my test method? Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

Manager class instances are as below.

```
public class OrderController : BaseController
{
    OrderManager _orderManager;

    public OrderController()
    {
        _orderManager = new OrderManager();
    }

    //Order Controllers
}
```

Comment: How are you getting past `HttpContext` when unit testing in isolation? How is the controller arranged for the test? Provide a [mcve] that can give better context of the actual problem.

Comment: I think I cannot pass `HttpContext` in unit testing, thats my problem. Also, don't understand clearly by what do you mean in your second question. I'm doing this at the top of my `[TestClass]` :
`private readonly OrderController _orderController;

        public OrderTests()
        {
            _orderController = new OrderController
            {
                Request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(),
                Configuration = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration()
            };
        }`

Comment: There is too much details missing from this question for me to be able to effectively help you. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: The code shown has design issues. `HttpContext` will be null in unit tests. I have no idea where user manager or order manager comes from....etc. without proper details, not much can be done.

Comment: Okay, I'm not pro, but I don't understand why you ask to see where ordermanager/usermanager is coming from. I need to fake the unit test as if I'm using an authenticated user. People use mock for these kind of issues, but I couldn't find my way out of Moq. I edit my question to make it show where manager classes are coming from.

Comment: This would be an integration test, not a unit test. This integration test of your controller, hits several business rules which are tested in one controller. This means it's integration and not a unit. A unit test would be for your service layer, like `_orderManager.CheckOrderQRFraud()` or `UserManager().IdentifyToken`. Those are things declared in an interface, which makes them unit testable. An integration test will hit several units of work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use TestServer to test your API methods

```
 using (var server = TestServer.Create<Startup>())
    {
        var result = await server.HttpClient.GetAsync("api/Orders/id");
        string responseContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Orders>>(responseContent);
        // other code
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

After spending another day to learn more about Unit Test, I found out that I need to treat (test in other word) each method seperately. If I'm not mistaken, that is also the point where Unit Test name is coming from.

So, first of all, I test this `UserManager().IdentifyToken(identity);` method of mine as below.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void IdentifyToken_Returns_UserWM_On_Successful_Request()
    {
        UserManager userManager = new UserManager();

        MD5Hasher passwordHasher = new MD5Hasher();

        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "creditmaster@admin.com"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Hash, passwordHasher.Encrypt("qW12345?"))
        };

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        identity.AddClaims(claims);

        var testResult = userManager.IdentifyToken(identity);

        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(UserWM), testResult.GetType());
    }
```

After receiving a successful test response, I carry on with `_orderManager.GetSingleOrderWithUserPaymentAccountBy(user.UserID, id));` as shown below.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetSingleOrderWithUserPaymentAccountBy_Returns_OrderWM_On_Successful_Request()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomUser = rnd.Next(0, 690);
        int randomOrder = rnd.Next(0, 40);

        OrderManager orderManager = new OrderManager();
        UserManager userManager = new UserManager();

        List<UserWM> userList = userManager.GetAllUser();
        var user = userList[randomUser];

        List<OrderWM> orderList = orderManager.GetAllOrder();
        var order = orderList[randomOrder];
        string orderCode = "HHBI5OBFWG5WDSKP";

        var testResult = orderManager.GetSingleOrderWithUserPaymentAccountBy(user.UserID, orderCode);

        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(OrderWM), testResult.GetType());
    }
```

In the end, if you could successfully unit test all your methods seperately, then they would work successfully when they are called simultaneously..

I also like to share below test method where I unit test my method (name is InsertUser) which insert users to database after all mandatory properties related with user entity filled as intended.

Tricky part is, this `InsertUser` contains too many `if-else` validation controls, such as,

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName))
        {
            throw new BusinessException(JsonResponse.CreateBusinessExceptionResponse(ErrorMessageConstants.UserFirstnameEmptyError), "");
        }
```

As there is too much code lines being talked about here, I do not want you to get lost around them, thus not sharing the whole `Insert User`.

If you have also run into a similar case in your unit tests, the only thing you should do is to gather these validations into another method (I named it InsertUserValidation). So, now we have two different methods: `InsertUser` and `InsertUserValidation`.

Now maybe you are asking why do we have to split validations from the main method. In my case, I have time dependent validations like below.

```
        if (activationRequest == null)
        {
            throw new BusinessException(JsonResponse.CreateBusinessExceptionResponse(ErrorMessageConstants.UserActivationCodeNotRequested), "");
        }
        else if (activationRequest.CreationTime.AddMinutes(3) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            throw new BusinessException(JsonResponse.CreateBusinessExceptionResponse(ErrorMessageConstants.UserActivationCodeIsTimedOut), "");
        }
```

Think about it, as time period between two `Unit Test` is unclear, you need to put these kind of validations into a different method, so you can mock them as described in below test method. For example, maybe I run my related method which creates that `activationRequest` five minutes ago, and I run my InsertUser method now. If I did't seperate this validation, InsertUser would still contain that above validation and it is going to throw exception as it is already more than three minutes when called.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void InsertUser_Returns_UserWM_On_Successful_Request()
    {
        UserManager userManager = new UserManager();

        MD5Hasher passwordHasher = new MD5Hasher();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int dummyEmailName = rnd.Next(0, 700);
        string dummyEmail = dummyEmailName.ToString() + "@gmail.com";

        UserActivationRequest userActivationRequest = new UserActivationRequest
        {
            EMail = dummyEmail,
            ActivationCode = "444855",
            IsUsed = false,
            IsActive = true,
            ConfirmationType = 1,
            ReadCount = 0
        };

        UserCreateAccountWM userCreateAccountWM = new UserCreateAccountWM()
        {
            FirstName = "Unit",
            LastName = "Test",
            Email = dummyEmail,
            Password = passwordHasher.Encrypt("yC123456?"),
            CountryID = 1,
            PhoneCountryCode = 90,
            MobileNumber = "5327894512",
            ActivationCode = "444855"
        };

        var validationMock = new Mock<UserManager>();
        validationMock.CallBase = true;
        validationMock.Setup(x => x.InsertUserValidation(It.IsAny<UserCreateAccountWM>())).Returns(userActivationRequest); //if your validations do not return anything back, just forget about the part with .Returns()

        var testResult = validationMock.Object.InsertUser(userCreateAccountWM);

        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(UserWM), testResult.GetType());
    }
```

Yes, if I'm not mistaken, you still need to create related entities.

Before I finish, I used Moq framework, and don't forget that methods you are seperating should be still under the same namespace.

Hope I would be helpful to those who are new to all these.

Comment: your answer is not complete: what is MD5Hasher, where do I reference it from? 
I think after your first block of code, the rest is off-topic and useless. Please consider to provide complete solutions focused on the specific problem and skip those parts which aren't valuable for the topic.

Comment: @LeonardoX MD5Hasher is the class where I turn plain texts to encrypted text. My answer would be useless IF I share all these not-related functions. Just use your brain for a little before copy-paste whole the code block!

Comment: your answer is not verifiable, as not all the code is provided, at least you should provide MD5Hasher.Encrypt method. Also, as pointed by other people, you provide unnecessary details, as I said in my previous comment, your question is related to test jwt authentication token, not "insert user" or "validate user" feature, which has nothing to do with the topic, so again, please, I encourage you to reformulate your answer